# CPanel installation on Azure CentOS, gcc install fails

Tags: centos6, azure

I am trying to install CPanel on a Centos VM on windows azure. Yum is failing to install gcc, which is required by the cpanel installer.

I am getting this

```
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.80.el6.i686 (base)
2013-02-22 13:08:24  709 (DEBUG):                Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6
2013-02-22 13:08:24  709 (DEBUG):                Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64 (@updates)
2013-02-22 13:08:24  709 (DEBUG):                    glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6_3.6
2013-02-22 13:08:24  709 (DEBUG):                Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64 (base)
2013-02-22 13:08:24  709 (DEBUG):                    glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6
```

I think the main issues stems from the fact that I had to comment out my updates repository because it was constantly giving errors.

Centos 6.3 azure update repo

```
#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Gives the following constant errors

```
# sudo yum update all
Loaded plugins: security
base      | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras    | 3.5 kB     00:00
openlogic | 1.3 kB     00:00
updates   | 3.5 kB     00:00
http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/6/updates/x86_64/repodata/41734c6392fbfa51abb5fb73887b5167c0780eeb485b236bc0eccfd1fc3d6245-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/6/updates/x86_64/repodata/41734c6392fbfa51abb5fb73887b5167c0780eeb485b236bc0eccfd1fc3d6245-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/41734c6392fbfa51abb5fb73887b5167c0780eeb485b236bc0eccfd1fc3d6245-primary.sqlite.bz2 from updates: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
[indice@indice-centos2 ~]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: security
http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/6/updates/x86_64/repodata/41734c6392fbfa51abb5fb73887b5167c0780eeb485b236bc0eccfd1fc3d6245-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/41734c6392fbfa51abb5fb73887b5167c0780eeb485b236bc0eccfd1fc3d6245-primary.sqlite.bz2 from updates: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Could you please post some advice?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your yum cache? `yum clean all`

Comment: Is this a brand new CentOS install? I just did a cPanel install the other day; I installed the minimal CentOS system, did `yum install perl`, and then was able to install cPanel. Seems like you have a CentOS installation to me...

Comment: Are you sure those are the only errors it gives you?  There isn't any apparent conflict there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The people who built that virtual machine image disabled updating it by the simple expedient of running their own CentOS mirror, which they don't keep in sync with upstream, and then altering the yum configuration to only use their mirror.

As you've noticed, their mirror repository isn't exactly perfect.

You can replace their yum configuration files (in the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory) with ones from a standard CentOS system, which is what I did.

Keep in mind that if you do this, you will no longer get updates to the Hyper-V Integration Services package that is in their repository; you'll have to update that yourself manually. You also will need to update the [Windows Azure Linux Agent](https://github.com/windows-azure/walinuxagent) yourself from Microsoft's github.

Comment: FWIW, the Integration Services package is built-in to CentOS 6.4 and up. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn531026.aspx