# Yum updates for CentOS by OpenLogic fails on Microsoft Azure

Tags: yum, azure, centos6.5

Earlier today I made a fresh install of CentOS in Azure from images provided by OpenLogic.

When I try to update the system with `yum update`, I get:

```
Loaded plugins: security
http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14]     PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net'"
Trying other mirror.
http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/6/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net'"
Trying other mirror.
```

..and two more...

```
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Has the hostname changed or is it temporarily unavailable?

Regards Niklas

Comment: check this: http://serverfault.com/questions/481501/cpanel-installation-on-azure-centos-gcc-install-fails

Comment: 'yum clean all' doesn't help. The only difference is that I get this message instead:
"yum update
Loaded plugins: security
http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net'"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again"

Comment: You should check its answer `You can replace their yum configuration files (in the /etc/yum.repos.d directory) with ones from a standard CentOS system`

Answer (score 1):

The error you recieve is because (as mentioned) the domain does not exist. I tried resolving the domain and it seems not to be working. Since this is a Windows Azure image it might be prefferable to ask their support what the new Centos Base repo mirror is. Or that you manually change it via `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file.

A sample one:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

to be sure. Copy the file that you have to file.bak

edit the first file and change to a mirror close to your "cloud" server.

http://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/

Found another good source :)

http://www.openlogic.com/azure/azure-centos-62-update-instructions/

A quick last comment;

Depending on packages installed and versions thereof you should be very careful, the resource you are trying to update from does not exist anymore, I would first check with Openlogic on what the REPO url is. Then check with the internal Azure support. In the third step I would switch out the repo for the real clean ones provided by CentOS but this can have unforeseen consequences.